# Setup a Task to run a file outside of the workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

Does tasks in code allow loading external executable files from a directory outside of the workspace ?

The following is attempting to run a executable file from a folder outside of the workspace.

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
        "taskName": "EXRTool",
        "type": "shell",
        "windows": {
            "command": "C:\\Custom Program Settings\\EXRTools\\exrdisplay.exe"
        },
```

This is my `tasks.json` file; and what I want to do is two things, first load a executable file that resides in a folder outside of my workspace, second; run a windows command line file as a task.  Without going into too much detail, I've tried many property setting options in the `tasks.json` file in all attempts, it fails with this error

```
> Executing task in folder CodeProjects: C:\Custom Program Settings\EXRTools\exrdisplay.exe <

The terminal shell CWD "\\Custom Program Settings\Projects.Code" does not exist

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tasks in visual studio code do not like spaces in file paths; the solution was to create a Powershell script, which enable the file to be executed from a path with spaces.  As well visual studio code, by default is set for Powershell rather then CMD.